# Creating an image for a desktop in Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I have a friend who lives a distance away from me. I have Hyper-V on my Win 10 computer. Is it possible to create an ISO with the OS and machine specific drivers in Hyper-V, and then load it onto the device via USB stick?

Comment: If you want to move a VM, use export/import to move the VM.  ISOs aren't meant for what you're doing.

Comment: Did your friend need to install the system on the physical host? Or install the system 
 on Hyper-V VM?

Comment: Physical host. I got the base OS installed. Now I'm having troubles getting it connected to the Internet as Hyper-V isn't sharing my wireless NIC with the VM.